# sticky position doesn't work but work in section

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

when I put a sticky postion on banner 1 and banner 2 it doesn't work but when I put it on the section encompassing the 2 it works, but I don't want to put it on the section but on the divs of banner 1 and banner 2.

i use tailwind and i haven't css

`

```
  <!-- Banner 1 Name -->
  <div class="sticky top-0 z-50">
    <h1 class="text-neutral-950 my-10 mr-10 font-light text-lg md:text-5xl leading-10 border-y-4 border-r-4 py-3 pr-8 pl-32 rounded-r-xl border-current bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-sm">
      Valentin Fiess
    </h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Message bienvenue -->
  <div id="welcome-message" class="font-light animate__animated animate__tada animate__infinite animate__slower text-center text-red-400 text-xl md:text-6xl">Bienvenue! </div>

  <!-- Banner 2 contact -->
  <div class="flex justify-end align-center ml-10 my-10 border-y-4 border-l-4 py-3 pr-2 rounded-l-xl border-neutral-950 bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-sm sticky top-0 z-50">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/valentin-fiess/" target="_blank" class="fab fa-linkedin mx-5 font-light" style="color: neutral-950;" title="Linkedin">
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/ValMtp3" target="_blank" class="fa-brands fa-square-github mx-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="GitHub">
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:valentin@epsi.fr" target="_blank" class="fa-solid fa-square-envelope mx-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="Mail">
    </a>
    <a href="assets_index/CV Valentin.pdf" target="_blank" class="fa-solid fa-address-card ml-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="CV">
    </a>
  </div>

</section>
```

`

i would the banner 1 and banner 2 is always sticky at the top but not the welcome message

Comment: FYI: `a` and `button` are both considered interactive elements, and as such MUST NOT be nested in HTML. If you want a link to _look_ like a button - then format it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I changed this, but it's not linked to my problem.

Comment: https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: div with overflow: auto and max-height: 100vh is used as the parent container. This allows the content to be scrollable vertically while making the banners sticky within that container.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 
    .scrollable-container {
      overflow: auto;
      max-height: 100vh;
    }

    .banner {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 50;
    }

    .banner1 {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .banner2 {
      background-color: #e5e5e5;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .welcome-message {
      text-align: center;
      color: red;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="scrollable-container">
    <div class="banner banner1">
      <h1>Banner 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="welcome-message">
      <h2>Bienvenue! </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="banner banner2">
      <h1>Banner 2</h1>
    </div>
 <div class="sticky top-0 z-50">
    <h1 class="text-neutral-950 my-10 mr-10 font-light text-lg md:text-5xl leading-10 border-y-4 border-r-4 py-3 pr-8 pl-32 rounded-r-xl border-current bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-sm">
      Valentin Fiess
    </h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Message bienvenue -->
  <div id="welcome-message" class="font-light animate__animated animate__tada animate__infinite animate__slower text-center text-red-400 text-xl md:text-6xl">Bienvenue! </div>

  <!-- Banner 2 contact -->
  <div class="flex justify-end align-center ml-10 my-10 border-y-4 border-l-4 py-3 pr-2 rounded-l-xl border-neutral-950 bg-sky-600 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur-sm sticky top-0 z-50">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/valentin-fiess060502/" target="_blank" class="fab fa-linkedin mx-5 font-light" style="color: neutral-950;" title="Linkedin">
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/ValMtp3" target="_blank" class="fa-brands fa-square-github mx-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="GitHub">
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:valentin@epsi.fr" target="_blank" class="fa-solid fa-square-envelope mx-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="Mail">
    </a>
    <a href="assets_index/CV Valentin.pdf" target="_blank" class="fa-solid fa-address-card ml-5" style="color: neutral-950;" title="CV">
    </a>
  </div>

</section>


  </div>
```